# How to reuse Expo's Audio object for recordings?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to implement a way for users to record and send their voice recordings. I've managed to get it working (kind of), however I'm unsure as to whether or not this is the correct approach. Currently, when a user presses and holds the record button, I create a new `Audio` object, initialize it and then invoke [`startAsync`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#startasync). Here's that bit of code:

```js
const recording = React.useRef<Audio.Recording | null>(null);

const startRecording = React.useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        recording.current = new Audio.Recording();

        recording.current.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate((...args) => {
            // some logic
        });

        recording.current.setProgressUpdateInterval(50);

        await recording.current.prepareToRecordAsync({
            isMeteringEnabled: true,
            android: {
                extension: '.mp3',
                outputFormat: AndroidOutputFormat.MPEG_4,
                audioEncoder: AndroidAudioEncoder.AAC,
                sampleRate: 44100,
                numberOfChannels: 2,
                bitRate: 128000,
            },
            ios: {
                extension: '.mp3',
                outputFormat: IOSOutputFormat.MPEG4AAC,
                audioQuality: IOSAudioQuality.MAX,
                sampleRate: 44100,
                numberOfChannels: 2,
                bitRate: 128000,
                linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
                linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
                linearPCMIsFloat: false,
            },
            web: {
                mimeType: 'audio/webm',
                bitsPerSecond: 128000,
            },
        });

        await recording.current.startAsync();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failed to start recording', err);
        recording.current = null;
    }
}, []);
```

So there are some issues with this bit. Every time the user wants to record a voice message, (which could be very frequently), I have to create a new `Audio` object (`new Audio.Recording()`) and then do some async stuff to prepare it.

UX takes a further hit because of asynchronicity once the user is done that specific recording:

```js
const stopRecording = React.useCallback(async () => {
    await recording.current.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        
    const uri = recording.current.getURI();
    console.log('uri', uri);
    recording.current = null;
}, []);
```

My question is whether or not it's possible to instantiate it once and then just "empty" it out, so that I may reuse the same, prepared object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Expo `Audio.Recording` API](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#recording), I do not see any "reset/empty/clean" built-in method for reuse in the way traditional objects might be reused or reset.

> That class represents an audio recording. After creating an instance of this class, `prepareToRecordAsync` must be called in order to record audio. Once recording is finished, call `stopAndUnloadAsync`. Note that only one recorder is allowed to exist in the state between `prepareToRecordAsync` and `stopAndUnloadAsync` at any given time.

Once a recording is stopped and unloaded using `stopAndUnloadAsync`, the `Audio.Recording` object cannot be reused for a new recording session. You must instantiate a new `Audio.Recording` object for each new recording session.

```bash
User Interaction          App Logic                 Expo Audio API
      │                        │                              │
      ├──── Press Record ──────>                              │
      │                        │                              │
      │                        ├─── new Audio.Recording() ────> 
      │                        │                              │
      │                        ├─ prepareToRecordAsync() ─────> 
      │                        │                              │
      │                        ├─────── startAsync() ─────────> 
      │                        │                              │
      │                        │<──── Recording Starts ───────┤ 
      │                        │                              │
      │<────── UX Update ──────┤                              │
```

While you cannot "empty" and directly reuse an `Audio.Recording` object in the Expo app, by managing the lifecycle of the recording sessions efficiently and providing clear UX signals during the recording preparation and cleanup phases, you can achieve a smooth and efficient user experience.

For example, you could display a loading indicator or disable the record button briefly while the recording is being prepared, signaling to the user that something is happening.

After a recording is stopped, unloaded, and the URI is retrieved, make sure to properly handle the cleanup of the recording object by setting it to `null` (for memory management and to avoid potential leaks).

```js
const stopRecording = React.useCallback(async () => {
    if (recording.current) {
        await recording.current.stopAndUnloadAsync();
            
        const uri = recording.current.getURI();
        console.log('uri', uri);
        // Cleanup after retrieving URI
        recording.current = null;
    }
}, []);
```

---

You could also consider using React's [`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) or [`useReducer`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer) for managing the recording state, which could provide a more streamlined way to handle the recording's lifecycle states (e.g., idle, recording, finished).

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

// define state hooks for managing the recording state and the `Audio.Recording` objects
const MyRecorderComponent = () => {
    const [recording, setRecording] = useState<Audio.Recording | null>(null);
    const [recordState, setRecordState] = useState<'idle' | 'recording' | 'finished'>('idle');
};

const startRecording = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
        await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
        await newRecording.startAsync();

        // Update state to reflect that recording has started
        setRecording(newRecording);
        setRecordState('recording');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
}, []);

const stopRecording = useCallback(async () => {
    if (recording) {
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        const uri = recording.getURI();
        console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);

        // Reset state
        setRecording(null);
        setRecordState('finished');
    }
}, [recording]);
```

Use in your component the `recordState` to control the UI, showing different options based on whether the app is idle, recording, or has finished recording:

```js
return (
    <div>
        {recordState === 'idle' && <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>}
        {recordState === 'recording' && <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>}
        {recordState === 'finished' && <p>Recording finished. Ready to record another.</p>}
    </div>
);
```

---

> I'm making a recording feature similar to that of WhatsApp. Which means I can't be invoking `await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync` every time.

Then an alternative approach would be to prepare the recording object ahead of time and reuse it, minimizing the delay when starting a new recording. As mentioned above, directly reusing the `Audio.Recording` object is not possible due to the Expo API constraints. So you would need to streamline the recording process to be as responsive as possible: that means preloading as much as possible, and reducing the operations performed during the recording start/stop phases.

When your component is mounted, or at a strategic point in your app's flow, prepare an `Audio.Recording` object in advance. That way, the recording can start more quickly when the user initiates it.

Implement a minimal delay between stopping a recording and preparing the next one, so the app is always ready for the next user action.

Use React's `useEffect` to handle preparation and cleanup, making sure the recording is ready when needed and resources are released appropriately.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

const MyRecorderComponent = () => {
    const [recording, setRecording] = useState<Audio.Recording | null>(null);
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

    // Prepare the recording in advance
    useEffect(() => {
        const prepareRecording = async () => {
            const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
            await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
            setRecording(newRecording);
            setIsReady(true);
        };

        prepareRecording();

        // Cleanup function to unload the recording when component unmounts
        return () => {
            if (recording) {
                recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
            }
        };
    }, [recording]);

    const startRecording = useCallback(async () => {
        if (isReady && recording) {
            await recording.startAsync();
            // Other logic to handle recording start
        }
    }, [isReady, recording]);

    const stopRecording = useCallback(async () => {
        if (recording) {
            await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
            // Logic to handle after recording is stopped
            // Optionally, prepare the next recording immediately after stopping
            setIsReady(false);
            const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
            await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
            setRecording(newRecording);
            setIsReady(true);
        }
    }, [recording]);

    return (
        <div>
            {isReady && <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>}
            {!isReady && <p>Preparing...</p>}
            {/* Additional UI for stopping recording and handling the recorded data */}
        </div>
    );
};
```

That would prepare an `Audio.Recording` object in advance and re-prepares a new one immediately after a recording is stopped, keeping the app ready for the next recording: doing so immediately after a recording is stopped rather than right before a new one starts should enhance the perceived responsiveness of your app.

Comment: I will be marking your answer as the correct one if no one else answers by the time the bounty expires. I'm making a recording feature similar to that of WhatsApp. Which means I can't be invoking `await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync` every time.

Comment: @MikeK In that case, would an alternative approach where you would preload as much as possible and reduce the operations performed during the recording start/stop phases be of interest?

Comment: Absolutely, I'd like the behavior to be as seemless as possible. If I want to record a voice message *right after* recording a previous audio message (again, as in WhatsApp, Telegram, etc), then I shouldn't feel a noticeable delay. I'd imagine you'll offer to prepare the first audio recording before the user presses the record button and then, after they're done, eagerly prepare all n + 1 *after* the first recording has been unloaded? I can't believe the API doesn't have an "empty" method :(

Comment: @MikeK Yes, that would be idea.

Comment: @MikeK I have edited the answer to illustrate that other option.